# Unable to get property 'scopeName'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I've done a google search for this error:

```
TypeError: Unable to get property 'scopeName' of undefined or null reference
```

In IE8 and can't find a single reference to this error.  I'm fairly certain that I've checked my markup for unclosed tags as I'm aware that IE8 routinely chokes on those.  It's an AngularJS application.  I'm at a loss here, and I was just wondering if anyone else had run across this error.

Comment: Other browsers don't do this? Perhaps they fail silently but still have the issue? The problem isn't the property, the problem is that it's looking for it on an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: You have mentioned scopeName somewhere in your javascript code that your browser is not able to understand.

Comment: Turns out it was a stray character in a <table>. Same as the nodeName errors I was seeing for IE9.

Answer (score 3):

> Turns out it was a stray character in a `<table>`. Same as the nodeName errors I was seeing for IE9.

Credit to OP for the answer in [his own comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653858/unable-to-get-property-scopename#comment38217525_24653858).

Comment: Thank you for making it an answer, would be great for OP to check this as accepted or answer his own question and accept it, I'd gladly upvote!